# How can explain the F# type casting output?

Tags: casting, f#

I had a problem about F# type casting. Here is the code.

```
type Person() =
    abstract member SayMe : unit -> unit
    default u.SayMe() = printfn "Hi, I am a person."
type Student() =
    inherit Person()
    override u.SayMe() = printfn "Hi, I am a student."
let x = Person()

let x1 = Student()

let x2 = x1 :> Person

x2.SayMe()|>ignore       
//***Output:"Hi, I am a student."
```

x2 is Person type. The output should be "Hi, I am a person."

How can explain it?

Comment: It appears you are confusing .net inheritance with C++ inheritance.

Comment: @mydogisbox : This is hiding vs. overriding – both C# and C++ can express both equally, the issue is essentially language-agnostic.

Comment: @ildjarn Ah, right you are.  I guess I've never used inheritance in C# enough to hit that.  Covered that pretty well when I learned C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noticed, `override` syntax is for defining **virtual members**.
Simply speaking, calling a *virtual* method does exactly what you are seeing: regardless of any *upcasts*, the actual method to call will be found according to the actual type of the object referred to, not to the type of the reference.

[This document (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx) provides with more details.

If you really don't want the method to be virtual, don't use `override`. This way, a method in a derived class will **hide** its parent's method.
Here's the full code:

```
type Person() =
    member u.SayMe() = printfn "Hi, I am a person."
type Student() =
    inherit Person()
    member u.SayMe() = printfn "Hi, I am a student."

let x = Student()
x.SayMe()             // prints "Hi, I am a student."
(x :> Person).SayMe() // prints "Hi, I am a person."
```

Answer (score 2):

x2 is still actually a student - for example

```
x2 :?> Student
```

works fine but

```
x :?> Student
```

will crash at run time.

The behaviour that you observe is completely expected for F#, as the overridden functions are still used after a downcast.

Comment: I Know x1 is Student type. How can I call Person.SayMe() using type casting?